# Does facebook-ios-sdk use the iOS 6 Facebook integration to support sign-on without opening the native Facebook app?

Tags: single-sign-on, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to figure out whether the latest facebook-ios-sdk (v3.0.8) is supposed to automatically make use of the new iOS 6 Facebook integration to support "Login with Facebook" without delegating to the native Facebook app.

The post at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/ says "In iOS 6, Apple is introducing Facebook integration built into iOS directly, which further simplifies the process" and "The Facebook SDK for iOS will automatically choose the best option when you attempt to use Facebook login".

In my app on iOS 6, Facebook login is still delegating to the Facebook app (I'm signed into Facebook in the iOS Settings screen, and I believe everything else is in order).  Does anyone know exactly what the behavior of Facebook login should be on iOS 6?  Should the process look different than on iOS 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ the following message is displayed:

> Upgrade to 3.0 SDK. We will be adding support for the much anticipated iOS 6 integration to the SDK in the coming weeks.

So, unfortunately it looks like we have to be patience.

Comment: Thanks, Robin.  I don't know how I missed that.  I wish I'd noticed it before I reread all of the docs.  =)

It's unfortunate their SDK wasn't ready for the iOS 6 launch...

Comment: If anyone happens to know if their SDK will just magically start working with the new iOS 6 features sometime soon vs. requiring an update of the SDK and re-release of apps using Facebook Login, please drop a note.  Thanks!

Comment: As of today 3.1 is available which implements the support.

Answer (score 1):

this is Shireesh from Facebook. As rightly said by Robin, the iOS SDK update with the iOS 6 integration will be out very shortly in the coming weeks. It will have support for Native login from iOS 6 settings.

Answer (score 0):

It was released today, Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 with native login and native share.